# Approximation of absolute value function using polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

By Stone-Weierstrass theorem, the set of polynomial is dense in $C[a,b]$, I am wondering what is the sequence of polynomial which can approximate absolute value function $|x|$? I know using $\sqrt{x^{2}+1/n}$ can approximate it but it is not a polynomial.

Comment: You can probably just pick $n$ points that range over the interval and construct the [interpolating polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) through those points. It won't be a nice sequence as $n$ increases, but I think it converges uniformly if you pick the points nicely.

Comment: Weierstrass' can be proven constructively using the [Bernstein polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial#Approximating_continuous_functions). You can scale your problem to the interval $[0,1]$ and then take the combination in the link of the first few Bernstein polynomials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, you can consider the binomial expansion of $\sqrt{1-y}$ on $[0,1]$. Namely, setting $y=1-x^2$, we have
$$
|x|=\sqrt{1-y}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{m}(-y)^m, \quad x\in[-1,1].
$$